# if request has content-type as application/json, how does cakephp fit the payload into $this->request->data?

Tags: json, angularjs, cakephp, payload

I noticed that my `angularjs` needs to set headers as the following in order for it to work nicely with `CakePHP`.

```
angularApp.config(function ($httpProvider) {
  $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
  $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
  $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Accept'] = 'application/json';
  $httpProvider.defaults.transformRequest = function(data) {
      if (data === undefined) {
          return data;
      }
      return $.param(data);
  }
});
```

My `CakePHP` is 2.4 and uses `JsonView` to render ajax requests.

My question is that the `angularjs` default header for `Content-Type` is `application/json;charset=utf-8` and if I use that as default and `JSON.stringify` my data,

can `CakePHP` work with that?

If not, what changes do I need to make to my code within `CakePHP` context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading [this](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#accessing-xml-or-json-data) tells us that:

if your `Content-Type` is the usual `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, then even if you send an `ajax` request, `CakePHP` will help you parse the payload into `$this->request->data` properly.

However, if `Content-Type` is `application/json`, then you need to use `$this->request->input('json_decode')`

Basically, we assume your angularjs config is:

```
angularApp.config(function ($httpProvider) {
  // because you did not explicitly state the Content-Type for POST, the default is application/json
  $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
  $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Accept'] = 'application/json';
  $httpProvider.defaults.transformRequest = function(data) {
      if (data === undefined) {
          return data;
      }
      //return $.param(data);
      return JSON.stringify(data);
  }
});
```

There is incomplete information there.

Assuming you are still taking in data and manipulate it as an array, you need to actually use `$this->request->input('json_decode', true)`.

To help matters, save this as either a protected method on AppController or at the appropriate controller.

```
protected function _decipher_data() {
    $contentType = $this->request->header('Content-Type');
    $sendsJson = (strpos($contentType, 'json') !== false);
    $sendsUrlEncodedForm = (strpos($contentType, 'x-www-form-urlencoded') !== false);

    if ($sendsJson) {
        $this->request->useful_data = $this->request->input('json_decode', true);
    }
    if ($sendsUrlEncodedForm) {
        $this->request->useful_data = $this->request->data;
    }
    return $this->request->useful_data;
}
```

Then in the appropriate action, you can do

```
$data = $this->_decipher_data();
$data['User']['id'] = $id;
```

OR

inside your beforeFilter you do this:

```
$this->_decipher_data();
```

then in the appropriate action, you do this:

```
$this->request->useful_data['User']['id'] = $id
```